# How to get a variable with the contents of a file on the filesystem?

Tags: search, register

I intend to use this to optionally share the search buffer between different Vim instances. I'll have a file on the filesystem that contains the content. So it means I need to set the search register with the contents of a file.

I'm hoping there's a clean Vimscript way to do this. It's ok if it uses python or any other language integration too.

I think this is how to edit the register: `let @/ = [whatever]`

Comment: For the record someone made a plugins which seems to be doing what you want: https://github.com/dahu/VimSharedSearch I've never tried it so I don't know what it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

This was easy.

```
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>n :let @/ = join(readfile(glob("~/.vim/.search")), "\n")<CR>
```